# Link to Pastebin'd code without triggering filter

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

It looks like someone has found a way to link to Pastebin provided code without triggering the filter. See [i586-mingw32msvc-g++ doesn't recognize boost and gmp links](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46615196/608639).

Comment: Links aren't clickable in code bodies.  This is not a new issue, but it can be addressed in the typical way: edit the question and put the contents of the paste in it.  However, given that the OP went with an image to show their error, closing it would be far better.

Comment: *Codeblocks* with a link in it are not subject to such blocks, by design. Just close such questions.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to remove the code block but then I encountered the filter. Since its 2017 and computers are supposed to work for us, perhaps the site should close the gap instead of making us work for the computers.

Comment: Well no...the standing advice would be to just close it since the link isn't the only problem with the question.

Comment: @Makoto I'd think that jww is referring to the fact that the question should no be able to be posted since it contains a bad link. So the advice to close a question with a bad links is actually working for the machine